# SQL query to scalar result in C#

Tags: c#, sql

In some programming contexts getting a scalar value from a sql query is easy:

```
RowCount = Connection.Execute("SELECT Count(*) FROM TableA").Fields(0).Value
```

In C#, given a SqlConnection variable `conn` that is already open, is there a simpler way to do this same thing without laboriously creating a SqlCommand, a DataReader, and all in all taking about 5 lines to do the job?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SqlCommand has an ExecuteScalar method that does what you want.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.region";
 Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the command object need to be specially handled with a `Dispose` or inside a `using` block?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  SqlCommand gets IDisposable from DbCommand.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer award because you gave `ExecuteScalar` first, though it would have been nice to have included the `using` info.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected.  ExecuteScaler is best used when you expect exactly one column and one row value as the return set. Such as an identity value or a count.  You don't need to dump it into a dataset and then try to read tables[0] rows[0] columns[0]

Answer (score 3):

If you can use LINQ2SQL (or EntityFramework) you can simplify the actual query asking to

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext("connectionString"))
{
    var rowCount = context.TableAs.Count();
}
```

If LINQ2SQL is an option that has lots of other benefits too compared to manually creating all SqlCommands, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which saves you at least from the `DataReader`:

```
static public int AddProductCategory(string newName, string connString)
{
    Int32 newProdID = 0;
    string sql =
        "INSERT INTO Production.ProductCategory (Name) VALUES (@Name); "
        + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = newName;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            newProdID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return (int)newProdID;
}
```

(Example taken from [this MSDN documentation article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

Comment: You were just a few seconds late to the party, so I'll mark you up. Why the shifting between `Int32` and `int`? Aren't they the same? Why not just use one?

Comment: Thanks, Erik. This is an example from MSDN. Int32 and int are just the same.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate Command.ExecuteScalar:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = mySql;
        var result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

If you're feeling really lazy, encapsulate it all in an extension method, like we do.

EDIT: As requested, an extension method:

```
public static T ExecuteScalar<T> (this SqlConnection connection, string sql)
{
    if (connection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("connection");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sql))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sql");
    }

    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        return (T)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Note, this version assumes you've properly built the SQL beforehand. I'd probably create a separate overload of this extension method that took two parameters: the stored procedure name and a List. That way, you could protect yourself against unwanted SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Do you have an example of an extension method you could share?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a DataReader. This example pulls back the scalar value:

```
Object result;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
       con.Open();
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLStoredProcName, con)) {
       result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
      }
}
```